# How make custom buttons/progressbar for VideoView or MediaController?

Tags: android, custom-controls, media-player, android-videoview

I want create MediaPlayer with custom design, but how to do it I can't find. I make streaming media player:

```
...
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vedio_view);
mBtnHttp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_http);
mBtnHttp.setOnClickListener(this);
mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mMediaController.show();
    }
...
```

Please, help me. I found a lot of topics in stackoverflow, but the problem was not solved!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, you want your own controls in media player or what ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you know, how do this?

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use Exoplayer to play your videos

```
dependencies {
   [...]

implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3'

}
```

use PlayerView instead of video view and give path to custom_playback_control in app:controller_layout_id attr

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView  
   android:id="@+id/video_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_control"/>
```

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#6